# Why is updateActionListener executed before actionListener of commandButton?

Tags: jsf

I use a commandButton on my page:

```
<h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{orderList.getCreateBatchOrderNav}" actionListener="#{orderList.createBatchOrder}" >
    <t:updateActionListener property="#{orderForm.orderId}"
                value="#{orderList.newCreatedBatchOrderId}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem is, that `updateActionListener` is executed before `actionListener` of `commandButton`. the value `orderList.newCreatedBatchOrderId` which is used from updateActionListener is only calculated when `orderList.createBatchOrder` is executed.

How can I change the execution order?

Comment: Which implementation and version of JSF do you use? Is it the same for `f:setPropertyActionListener`?

Comment: @Selaron: https://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_updateActionListener.html It's from Tomahawk, an old component library for JSF 1.x.

Comment: @BalusC yes, but there are variants of tomahawk usable with JSF 2.0 and [2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk/tomahawk21/1.1.14). In JSF 2+ the actionLister from attribute is normally processed first. For JSF 1: I don't know.

Comment: The project uses still the (very old) Version 1.1.1